# can boto3 cause EMRFS metadata inconsistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-emr

I am using boto3 SDK when running a python script in EMR cluster which has consistent view enabled. I am trying to debug an exception with the error message `Exception while invoking ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.mkdirs over null`

My question is can boto3 cause inconsistency in EMRFS metadata? Should we always use hadoop/hdfs commands over boto3 for copy/delete of s3 files/folders when executing from EMR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** boto3 will cause inconsistency. Even AWS CLI.

You need to manually [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-cli-reference.html) metadata after every copy/delete operation.

Using HDFS command emrfs will be in sync.